# Nodemon index.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, nodemon

I'm brand new to nodemon. After following the steps on this video at 12:01 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eB9Fq9I5ocs
,
I get the following errors when trying to run my app using nodemon:
[image]

HERE IS THE APP.JS file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Connect to Mongoose
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/ChatbotService')
var db = mongoose.connection;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Hola4');
});

app.listen(8601);
console.log('Running on port 8601...');
```

HERE IS THE PACKAGE.JSON FILE:

```
{
  "name": "chatbot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "chatbot app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "*",
    "body-parser": "*",
    "mongoose": "*"
  },
  "author": "Chris",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0"
  }
}
```

What do I need to do to get nodemon to find the index.js module?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to initialize nodemon. It might be helpful to also post your folder structure

Comment: agh sorry. just updated the question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is your main file is called app.js but in the package.json file your main file is index.js. You need to change it, so nodemon knows what file to look for:

```
"main": "app.js",
```

Comment: Can you provide your JS file and package.json / nodemon config?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't post any code for us to debug its a little impossible for us to do anything unless we watch the video(its an hour long) lol. But by the look at the error you forgot to put module.exports = "whatever is suppose to go here in index.js". Or you forgot to require it on your server.js/app.js file

Answer (score 0):

PS D:\react cource\i-notebook\backand> nodemon .\index.js
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- nodemon .\index.js
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nodemon:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

when i give comant i face a issue kidly help me

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32921875)