# {nodemon} app crashed - waiting for file changes before started

Tags: node.js, nodemon

First time making a discord bot but seem to be getting this issues

```
PS C:\Users\dylan\OneDrive\Desktop\ButteredCrisp Inc\ButteredCrisp Bot> nodemon
[nodemon] 3.0.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\dylan\OneDrive\Desktop\ButteredCrisp Inc\ButteredCrisp Bot\index.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:86:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.18.2
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Tried re installing node but still get the same issues

Comment: Seems you don't have an `index.js` file. What files do you have?

Comment: I am sorry still new at all of this what do you mean by what files do I have

Comment: `nodemon` runs script files. By default, it looks for a file named `index.js` to run but you don't appear to have a file with that name. What script file _would_ you like `nodemon` to run?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nodemon index.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42190362/nodemon-index-js)

Comment: Well Currently trying to make discord bot and I have the index.js in a src folder I am trying to run make run my discord bot

Comment: Follow the advice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42192395/283366) and set `"main": "src/index.js"` in your `package.json`

Comment: I did that and still getting the same thing after putting in "nodemon"

Comment: Then try using `nodemon src/index.js` instead

Comment: I get [nodemon] 3.0.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node src/index.js`
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart

Comment: `clean exit` means your program successfully ran to completion. If that is unexpected, you'll need to ask a new question and include the contents of your JS file(s)